# Angular NVD3 Line Chart Zoom - On Drag visible outside chart region

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

Angular NVD3 Line chart Zoom, able to drag outside the chart region. Is it possible to limit display chart data alone?

[image]

$scope.scaleGraphOptions = {
                            chart: {
                                type: 'lineChart',
                                height: 500,
                                margin : {
                                    top: 20,
                                    right: 20,
                                    bottom: 200,
                                    left: 50
                                },
                                x: function(d){ return d[0]; },
                                y: function(d){ return d[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfJwu.png); },
                                color: d3.scale.category10().range(),
                                duration: 300,
                                useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                                xAxis: {
                                    tickFormat: function(d){
                                        return $filter('date')(d, 'short');//d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)); //uncomment for date format
                                    },
                                    showMaxMin: false,
                                    rotateLabels:15,
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                    axisLabelDistance: 100,
                                },
                                forceY: $scope.forceY,
                                forceX: $scope.forceX,
                                zoom: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    scale:scale,
                                    scaleExtent: [1, 10],
                                    useFixedDomain: false,
                                    useNiceScale: false,
                                    horizontalOff: false,
                                    verticalOff: true,
                                    unzoomEventType: "dblclick.zoom",
                                }
                            }
                        };